# How to choose diode?

Tags: voltage, current, diodes

I built a scaled down model of my idea.  Since current flow was always under 1A, I used a 1N4007 diode to keep the current unidirectional in the circuit.

Now I am planning to build a full size model and I wish to keep the current unidirectional in this model also.  The current flow will be around 50A in the circuit and voltage being 36V.

- What diode should I use for this purpose?
- Is there some other suitable device for this purpose of mine?

Comment: What is your idea?  Can you provide a schematic drawing of the circuit with current and voltage indicated?

Comment: At 36 V, Schottky is probably your best option. Is 36 V the peak reverse voltage the diode need to withstand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are avaible big bridge rectifiers. They are very cheap - I would suggest using one of these with two diodes in parallel connected internally. They also come in different physical sizes as well as versions with possibility to attach to a heatsink. There are versions for 50A or even bigger currents.

Answer (score 1):

Other than simply bigger diodes (just heat sink thems!), some manufacturers make 'ideal diode controllers' that drives MOSFETs to do the same thing. TI and Analog for sure, with Analog making even a full bridge rectifer thingie driving mosfets (disclaimer: probably even Infineon, On Semi and all the others make these. I just know better these product lines).

It *could* be a little more expensive (but really big diodes are not much cheaper than power MOSFETs) but heat losses are much lower. Diodes have about a junction loss (and *big* diodes have more than 0.7V of Vf), MOSFET are mostly heating from RDSon and switching losses.

This is of course a suggestion for power line frequencies (up to maybe 500Hz), if you are going higher you should check the datasheet for suitability.